# How to list all com-ports?

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, pyserial

I installed pyserial using `pip install pyserial` and now I'm trying to run the code below to list all the comports on my desktop. I'm using PyCharm if that's important.

```
import serial.tools.list_ports

def serial_ports():
    print(list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serial_ports()
```

Right now it just prints out `[]` and nothing else. I'm not even sure if my computer has comports because when I checked [my device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PUEj.png) I didn't see anything called "Ports (COM & LPT)". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: _I'm not even sure if my computer has comports_ If your computer doesn't have any com ports, what do you expect the code to do?

Comment: What exactly were you expecting to show up in the list?  I'm not sure that any currently-available computer has a built-in COM or LPT port, you're most likely to see something like a USB-to-serial adapter.

Comment: It's very possible your computer doesn't have any.  You probably need to look at a USB-to-RS232 cable.  I'd recommend one with the FTDI chipset in it (such as this [one](https://www.amazon.com/Sabrent-Serial-Adapter-Chipset-CB-FTDI/dp/B006AA04K0/)--though I haven't used this model).  Avoid ones with the Prolific chipset... to many issues (such as dropping characters).  I imagine once you have something that can behave like a COM port, then your code might actually work. :-)

Comment: I'm trying to connect to an Arduino through a USB port and I figured the first step I need to do is figure out which port on my computer is connected to the Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: **Updated**

```
import sys
import glob
import serial


def serial_ports():
    """ Lists serial port names

        :raises EnvironmentError:
            On unsupported or unknown platforms
        :returns:
            A list of the serial ports available on the system
    """
    if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
        ports = ['COM%s' % (i + 1) for i in range(256)]
    elif sys.platform.startswith('linux') or sys.platform.startswith('cygwin'):
        # this excludes your current terminal "/dev/tty"
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty[A-Za-z]*')
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'):
        ports = glob.glob('/dev/tty.*')
    else:
        raise EnvironmentError('Unsupported platform')

    result = []
    for port in ports:
        try:
            s = serial.Serial(port)
            s.close()
            result.append(port)
        except (OSError, serial.SerialException):
            pass
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(serial_ports())
```

Comment: I get the empty brackets now with the updated code. Looks like -> ```[]```

Comment: Umm. Could you run this first in your cmd: `python -m serial.tools.list_ports`. It has to list ports

Comment: it says no ports found

Comment: Are you using `Anaconda`?

Comment: Is your `Pycharm project` linked to `Anaconda environment`?

Comment: I think I'm using a virtual environment called "Virtualenv", I'm not too sure. It looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/hG6g5Uu.png) when I create a new project.

Comment: First check if you really installed `pyserial`. In your Pycharm, go very below left, you should see **Terminal** button, click it and type `pip list`. And search for `pyserial`, to be sure if you really installed it

Comment: Yep, it's [there](https://i.imgur.com/JeIIawZ.png).

Comment: Now, in that Terminal window (same place) run this: `python -m serial.tools.list_ports`. It has to show list of ports

Comment: It still says that there are no ports found. [link](https://i.imgur.com/dPzwWgy.png)

Comment: Umm, then you should try a **different USB cable** and make sure you are not plugged into a USB hub. After that test above code

Comment: Probably it is not coding problem. Try this [link](https://windowsreport.com/arduino-port-not-showing-up/) to solve your issue. Then run above codes again. Seems like your problem is related to device or drivers

Comment: This is such a silly solution but after unplugging and plugging the device multiple times, it solved itself.